# Pivot Pandas Column of Lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column whose values are lists and where another column is a date. I would like to create a dataframe that counts the elements of the lists by date.

The dataframe looks like:

[image: image of dataframe. I'm not yet awesome enough to post pictures directly]

```
pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "col1": ["['a','b']", "['b','c']", "['a','c']", "", "['b']"],
        "col2": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
)
```

What I would like the dataframe to look like is:

[image: Image of desired dataframe]

```
pd.DataFrame(
    data={"a": [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], "b": [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], "c": [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]},
    index=["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05"],
)
```

Any thoughts on how to do this kind of transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`pd.crosstab`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) here.

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.findall('\w+')
df_ = df.explode('col1')
pd.crosstab(df_['col2'], df_['col1']).reindex(df_['col2'].unique()).fillna(0)

col1          a    b    c
col2                     
2020-01-01  1.0  1.0  0.0
2020-01-02  0.0  1.0  1.0
2020-01-03  1.0  0.0  1.0
2020-01-04  0.0  0.0  0.0
2020-01-05  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extractall` to extract the values inside `''`, then counts the values with `groupby`:

```
out= (df.col1.str.extractall("'([^']*)'")
   .groupby(level=0)[0].value_counts()
   .unstack(level=1,fill_value=0)
   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
)

out.index= df['col2']
print(out)
```

Output:

```
0           a  b  c
col2               
2020-01-01  1  1  0
2020-01-02  0  1  1
2020-01-03  1  0  1
2020-01-04  0  0  0
2020-01-05  0  1  0
```

Comment: This is a strong answer, thank you Quang.  However, I should have been more clear - in my dataset, dates can sometimes repeat, and I would like to sum the total of the variable for all occurrences of that date

Comment: @enixon4 Instead of `out.index=df['col2']` do `out.groupby(df['col2']).sum()` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "col1": [['a','b'], ['b','c'], ['a','c'], ['c'], ['b']],
        "col2": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05"],
    }
)
df2 = df.explode('col1').reset_index(drop=True)
df2["value"]=1
pd.pivot_table(df2, values="value", index=["col2"], columns=["col1"], aggfunc=lambda x: 1, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: I think this could be better if you did a crosstab instead of a pivot table, IMO

```pd.crosstab(index = df2.col2, columns = df2.col1)```. That would also allow you to forgo ```df2['value'] = 1```

Comment: Yes. I saw toue solution. Nice !