# pandas data frame to make words as columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

How to make unique words which are in a list format in every row of a dataframe a column

| name | desc |
| --- | --- |
| x | ['red','white','yellow'] |
| y | ['red','black','blue'] |

as

| name | red | white | yellow | black | blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | yes | yes | yes |  |  |
| y | yes |  |  | yes | yes |

Comment: Are the malformed data part of the actual input, or a transcription error? `white'` missing a quote, `['red','black','blue'` missing a closing bracket?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot Pandas Column of Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806982/pivot-pandas-column-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)/[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) :

```
#if necessary
# from ast import literal_eval
# df["desc"] = df["desc"].apply(literal_eval)
​
out = (df.explode("desc").pivot_table(index="name", columns="desc",
                                      sort=False, aggfunc=lambda x: "yes")
           .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  name  red white yellow black blue
0    x  yes   yes    yes   NaN  NaN
1    y  yes   NaN    NaN   yes  yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
tmp = df.explode('desc')

out = (
 pd.crosstab(tmp['name'], tmp['desc'])
   .replace({0: '', 1: 'yes'})
   .reset_index()
 )
```

*NB. I would remove the conversion to ''/'yes' and keep the 0/1.*

Output:

```
desc name black blue  red white yellow
0       x             yes   yes    yes
1       y   yes  yes  yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The pandas-only answers seem insanely complex to me; who wants to remember that syntax?

Here is a scikit-learn answer.

### A scikit-learn answer: [`sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#multilabelbinarizer)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['x', 'y'],
    'desc':['red white yellow'.split(), 'red black blue'.split()]
})

print(df)
```

```
  name                  desc
0    x  [red, white, yellow]
1    y    [red, black, blue]
```

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
ones_and_zeroes = binarizer.fit_transform(df['desc']) # magic happens here
df[binarizer.classes_] = ones_and_zeroes

print(df)
```

```
  name                  desc  black  blue  red  white  yellow
0    x  [red, white, yellow]      0     0    1      1       1
1    y    [red, black, blue]      1     1    1      0       0
```